# I need Push Notification show when my application opens like whatsapp, Viber in android(Phonegap)

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins, cordova-3, phonegap-pushplugin

I got success setup push notification using PushPlugin in android(Phonegap).I got Notification when my application close.
The problem is that I need Push Notification come when my application opens like whatsapp, Viber.
If it is possible in Phonegap?? 
Please help me or send me your valuable comment.

Comment: You question is not clear. Is your problem similar to this question: [How to handle Push notification when application is resumed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29204334/1761793) or any other question in the related sidebar? Do update your question with a clear problem, so that someone will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for Broadcast receivers, [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
Please check the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [local notification PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/b7b7b13/README.md). Make sure to include the dependence org.apache.cordova.device @ 0.2.12.

Thanks,
Madan