# Multiple push notification present in the status bar in android when the second is touched others vanish

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

I work with Notification GCM in cordova android apps.
when the application is running in background and a notification came
it is displayed in the status bar of the device.
when more than two notifications are displayed in this status bar, I tap on first notification (displayed in the status bar), the application opens and it displays the notification message, when I tap on the second notification all of the remaining notifications(in the status bar) vanish.
In this fonction, when I tap on the notification, the part (! e.foreground) runs.

```
function onNotificationGCM(e) {

  switch( e.event )
   {
    case 'message':


        if (e.foreground)
        {   
            // playAudio('http://oringz.com/oringz-uploads/sounds-1068-the-calling.mp3');
            navigator.notification.beep(1);
            msgNotification(e.payload.message);
            $("#toastContainer").dxToast('instance').show();
            var notif={message:e.payload.message};
            popovernotifListe.push(notif);
            nbrnotif(nbrnotif()+1);

        }
        else if (!e.foreground)
        {

             if (e.coldstart) {
                    console.log("App was not running and user clicked on notification");
            } else {
                console.log("App was running and user clicked on notification");
            }
            msgNotification(e.payload.message);
            $("#toastContainer").dxToast('instance').show();
            nbrnotif(nbrnotif()+1);
            var notif={message:e.payload.message};
            popovernotifListe.push(notif);

        }
        break;

        case 'error':
          console.log('GCM error = '+e.msg);
        break;

        default:
          console.log('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not downvoting this, but you *really* should improve your question. What would you like to happen? Could you show us some code?

Comment: I did it ( better explained with code )

Comment: Does this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29437083/1761793) help?

Comment: thank you for your help but this doesn't solve the problem, when I touched the second notification in the status bar, (when I have many), the others vanish in the status bar

Answer (score 3):

If the notification ID is not sent from your server, each notification is created with an ID `0`.

To fix this problem, you will have to set the [notification ID](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) for each notification you create. You can set the notification ID by sending a parameter `notID` from the server, with each notification, which will be used to [create a notification](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/android/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java#L126).